# Jupyter Lab Window Not Showing Properly

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I just installed Jupyter Lab and tried it, however it doesn't showup properly. I tried reinstalling and installing but it show the same bug.

I am using dell xps 13, I tried installing it using:

- 'pip install jupyterlab', and
- 'conda install -c conda-forge jupyterlab'

Both gave same error. Is there a solution to this? The Jupyter Notebook is working just fine.

[Jupyter Lab Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KxWMz.png)

Comment: What does it mean "it doesn't showup properly" ? icons not showing ?

Comment: When opened, the jupyter lab shows only a small portion of the windows such as shown in the image (link above). The rest of the screen is only gray.

Comment: Did you try using a different browser (e.g. firefox)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue using the pip-installed jupyter lab (Using Win64 with Python 3.6 in a virtualenv). Finally, I managed to run it by uninstalling the pip installer version and using the conda installer version:

- "pip uninstall jupyterlab"
- "conda install jupyterlab"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with jupyterlab-3.4.5 on firefox 104.0.

When I refreshed the browser (Alt R) it fixed the display.